# System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out, while calling WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, http, web

I'm not able to debug a self hosted WCF service from it's Web application client. And, I'm receiving an error as -
"

> **System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)**

"

I'm new to WCF service development.

I created a sample Wcf service, which automately created through Wcf template.
Then, I added a web reference to client webapplication, by using WCF service WSDL, and I'm trying to consume it by below code.

I tried to dispose the service and set some time out interval too.

```
WCFService.TESTWCF obj = new WCFService.TESTWCF();
obj.Timeout = 20000;  // I added this line of code to troubleshoot time out issue.

string s = obj.GetData();

obj.Dispose();  // I added this line of code to troubleshoot time out issue.
```

**See below WCF code for your reference.**

```
namespace TESTWCF
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData();

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Interface Implementation**

```
namespace TESTWCF
{
    public class TESTWCF_Kelly_IQN : IService
    {
        public string GetData()
        {
            return string.Format("You entered nothing");
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly which location do you get error  ? Also make sure you have not changed url after generating proxy class using Add Service Reference.

Comment: I'm receiving error at string s = obj.GetData();, I didn't change the URL, after generating the proxy.

Comment: your endpoint is probably wrong in web.config

Comment: Try adding your WCF service using Add **Service** Reference, not Add Web Reference.   I doubt this is the root cause of the issue, but Add Web Reference is a hold over from ASMX, which is legacy and no longer supported (though it is available for backwards-compatability).

Comment: @Tim, Yes your correct. Its working.